# How to clear all routes and push to index

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

i want to clear all routes and go to index ('/'). is there a way to achieve this ? thanks in advance

what i've done so far:

```
mounted() {
    var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
    if (perfEntries[0].type == 'reload') {
        //clear all routes
        //this.$router.push('/');
    }
},
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clear all routes"?

Comment: `this.$router.push('/');` is not working? 
If so, can you try this? 
this.$router.push({path: '/'})

Comment: @WildanMaulanaSyahidillah for example im in '/' then i navigate to '/test'. when i reload the in the '/test' page i want to go back to '/' without be able to go to 'test' by clicking <- button in the browser. i think if  i clear all the routes that i have visited then the <- -> button will be disabled?.

Comment: @NemanjaK it works but i want to clear the routes that i have visited before push to '/'

Comment: @hansCristian3799 I see. This could be a solution?
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-is-there-a-way-to-flush-the-history/6798/2

Comment: i dont think that its the same case as i have

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is right. Simply just do:

> this.$router.push('/pagename')

or

> this.$router.push({path: '/pagename', param: {param1: 'value1',
> param2: value2}) if you want to go to route with params

Comment: if i do this without clearing all routes that i have visited, then i can go back with the <- button in the browser and it will load the previous route that i have visited, i dont want that. when '/' is loaded i want it to be just when the web loaded first time the <- -> button disabled

Comment: Have you tried router.replace()? Reference to: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-replace-location-oncomplete-onabort

Comment: yes i have tried that, it works but  i guess what i wanted is when i reload the second page i want to go to '/' with <- -> button disabled  just when the web loaded for the first time